# how to call a jquery / java script variable acuretly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have `#cross_1 , #cross_2 , #cross_3 , #cross_4` 
and every `#cross_id` have each `#id_green`

not showing any result nor any error...

```
var setId = 2; 

var defaultTime = 3000;


$(document).ready(function () { 

    setLight(setId,defaultTime);

});

function setLight(setId,defaultTime) {


    //deactivateAll();

    activeGreen(setId,defaultTime);

}

function deactivateAll() {


    $('#cross_1 #id_red').addClass('red');

    $('#cross_2 #id_red').addClass('red');

    $('#cross_3 #id_red').addClass('red');

    $('#cross_4 #id_red').addClass('red');

}

function activeGreen(setId,defaultTime) {

    alert('#cross_'+setId+ '#id_green');

    $('#cross_'+setId+ '#id_green').addClass('green');

}


function activeYellow() {

    //$('#cross_'+setId+ ',#id_yellow').addClass('yellow');

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you should use IDs (#something) only once on any given page. Use classes for shared styling.

Comment: jQuery selector syntax aside, if you're saying that your html has more than one element with the same id ("id_green") then your html is invalid and you won't be able to reliably access those "id_green" elements from JS.

Comment: k can u give me a tutorial site for this classes for shared styling

Comment: I solved this is the righ syntext

$('#cross_'+setId+' #green').addClass('green');

Answer (score 2):

put a comma between each selector

```
$('#cross_'+setId+ ',#id_green').addClass('green');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its just your space in the jQuery selector that is in the wrong place

```
function activeGreen(setId,defaultTime) {
    $('#cross_'+setId+' #id_green').addClass('green');
}
```

If your structure is:

```
#cross_1
    #id_green
#cross_2
    #id_green
```

And so on, which is invalid html as mentioned by others